# Running Unit Testing with grunt

Tags: gruntjs

I added new code to existing code in angular.js.
Then i run the unit test by using "grunt" in the command line.
The following error showed up. Please see below.

I run 'grunt' in the Linux Terminal for unit testing and the following error showed up:
Fatal error: ENOENT, open 'logs/post.dispatch.error.log

Comment: You may want to try opening up the "logs/post.dispatch.error.log" file to see what other error messages reside inside...

Comment: thanks summea. I added some more code and try running the unit test again.